# How to track default events in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I want to subscribe to default events of Firebase Analytics.
For example, I want to know that event "app_update" is sending.
How to implement this feature, or it is not impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, [Google Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/) may suit your needs.